# Getting java.sql.Timestamp from ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime, java-time

I want to insert a value in a column of `datetime` datatype in database from Java based on some logic.

Logic: 
If the day of the month is 29, 30 or 31 then put in 28th of next month. Else put in the same day of the next month.

E.g. If date is `2017-08-31`, the date which will go in database will be `2017-09-28`. However, if date is `2017-08-27`, the date which will go in database will be `2017-09-27`.

I also want everything in `UTC`.

The code I am trying is this:

```
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

utcDateTime = utcDateTime.plusMonths(1);

if(utcDateTime.getDayOfMonth() >= 29){
    utcDateTime = utcDateTime.withDayOfMonth(28);
    Timestamp time = Timestamp.from(utcDateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(time); // DB insert here
}else{
       Timestamp time = Timestamp.from(utcDateTime.toInstant());
       System.out.println(time); // DB insert here
     }
```

Question: Is this the most correct approach or is there a simpler Java 8 way using `Instant` (which is always in UTC) ? I am not getting any way to directly get day of month from `Instant` object or way to add a month to `Instant` object.

Comment: Without thinking all possibilities through, immediately your code looks fine. `Instant` does not lend itself quite so well to the date arithmetic you need, so it’s probably best to use another class. I would consider `OffsetDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Do you need the time of day for anything? If not it may be more correct to use `LocalDate` (even when the conversion to `Instant` is a bit less straightforward). Also you may want to explain why you want to go back to September 28 when there are 30 days in September; it seems a little funny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine for your purpose. For your possible inspiration, here’s my version:

```
    OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    if (utcDateTime.getDayOfMonth() >= 29) {
        utcDateTime = utcDateTime.withDayOfMonth(28);
    } 

    utcDateTime = utcDateTime.plusMonths(1);
    Timestamp time = Timestamp.from(utcDateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(time); // DB insert here
```

I am using `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime` since we don’t need any of the extra functionality of a time zone, like summer time (DST) and historic offset changes. I am adding a month *after* adjusting the day-of-month. Both work, but this frees the reader from thinking about what happens when you add one month to, say, January 31. Finally I found the version without an `else` part more natural: in some cases you need to adjust the day-of-month, so the `if` part takes care of that, and in all other cases we just don’t make that adjustment. Take the pieces you like (if any) and discard the rest.

The code (both yours and mine) preserves the time-of-day. I suppose you wanted this. For the sake of completeness, if you don’t, you would want your database to hold just a date rather than a timestamp, so the code would use a `java.sql.Date`:

```
    LocalDate utcDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    if (utcDate.getDayOfMonth() > 28) {
        utcDate = utcDate.withDayOfMonth(28);
    }
    utcDate = utcDate.plusMonths(1);
    Date date = Date.valueOf(utcDate);
    System.out.println(date); // DB insert here
```

If you can’t change the database column datatype, it’s usual to use the start of day (0:00):

```
    Timestamp time = Timestamp.from(utcDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
    System.out.println(time); // DB insert here
```

Finally, I warmly encourage you to see if you can get a JDBC 4.2 driver for your database. This will accept inserting an `Instant` (or a `LocalDate`) directly, so you get completely rid of the outdated `Timestamp` class (or `Date`).